# Minimum and maximum of a float array in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have an array of floats in Bash:

For example:

```
array(1.0002, 1.00232, 1.3222, ....)
```

I want to find the maximum and the minimum element of the array using Bash.
The problem with this is that I have float elements that are not quite supported in Bash.

I have tried for example:

```
IFS=$'\n'
echo "${ar[*]}" | sort -nr | head -n1
```

But it does not work for floats.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain why it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably many ways and I don't claim the two following are "*the best*".

You could use a calculator that supports floats, like `bc`, for instance:

```
max="${array[0]}"
min="${array[0]}"
for v in "${a[@]}"; do
  max=$(echo "if($v>$max) $v else $max" | bc)
  min=$(echo "if($v<$min) $v else $min" | bc)
done
echo "max=$max"
echo "min=$min"
```

`awk` also supports floats, so the following would do the same:

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | \
awk '$1>max||NR==1 {max=$1}
     $1<min||NR==1 {min=$1}
     END {print "max=" max; print "min=" min}'
```

Comment: The first one gives me a syntax error, the second one works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @epushor What syntax error? Do you have `bc` installed? Do you have non-numeric values in your array?

Comment: the error is: (standard_in) 1: syntax error - that is all I get. I only have floats in my array.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Could be a `bc` error message. What version of `bc` do you have (what is the output of `bc --version`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=(1.0002 1.00232 1.3222)        
$printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | sort -rn | head -n1        
1.3222          
$ printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | sort -rn | tail -n1  
1.0002  
#Tried with %s or %f
```